Goal: A best fit Markdown representation of a Confluence page with tables and images using Pandoc and shell scripts
I am working to create a ci/cd pipeline for "documentation-as-code", where a number of Confluence pages need to be converted to Markdown and moved to a GIT repo. The Confluence pages contain tables as well as Gliffy images. In the lack of APIs for Confluence, my approach is to use the Word export from Confluence, and from there see what is possible to achieve with Pandoc and eventually some additional scripting in bash, Perl or Python. I also need to create nice looking PDFs from the Markdown files, and I have a pretty good setup for this with a custom Latex configuration. Apart from one sad fact - when the Markdown files (also created with a docx-->markdown conversion in Pandoc) use html elements to encode the tables from Word, Pandoc seem to ignore them completely when converting to PDF. I have experimented with different Markdown output formats in the docx-->markdown step as well as LUA filters, but with no luck. Any tips will be appreciated!

Below is a Lua filter that parses all raw HTML snippets to pandoc's internal document format. It's an ad-hoc adaption of the parse-latex filter, which does the same thing for LaTeX.
--- parse-html.lua – parse and replace raw HTML snippets
---
--- Copyright: © 2021–2024 Albert Krewinkel
--- License: MIT

-- Return an empty filter if the target format is HTML: the snippets will be
-- passed through unchanged.
if FORMAT:match 'html' then
  return {}
end

-- Parse and replace raw HTML blocks, leave all other raw blocks
-- alone.
function RawBlock (raw)
  if raw.format:match 'html' then
    return pandoc.read(raw.text, 'html').blocks
  end
end

-- Parse and replace raw HTML inlines, leave other raw inline
-- elements alone.
function RawInline(raw)
  if raw.format:match 'html' then
    return pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(
      pandoc.read(raw.text, 'html').blocks
    )
  end
end

Converting documents with --lua-filter=parse-html.lua should then give much better results.

Thanx @tarleb, it certainly gave better results using that lua filter. I need to do some additional cleanup, but I think I can do that with simple scripting.
